# how to save all items for each url

Tags: scrapy

I add a url list like this. When it goes to pipeline, it seems all items from the url list will be passed to process_item.

how to separate items according to the specific url? For example, to save items from one url to one file.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/1.html',
        'http://www.example.com/2.html',
        'http://www.example.com/3.html',
    ]
```

Comment: I will suggest braking your problem in two different parts will make your work easy. I am sure it can be done with one go but why make it complicated?. If you want to make individual file for every `unique url` and store the data in it -> Do this run the crawler and store it in one file and then making a custom python script to divide the file into individual files

Answer (score 0):

Add a ref_url to the item before yielding it, then check for it in the pipeline. There are other solutions, but this is the most direct one I guess.